# Python webdriver current window handle print to readable form

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, handle

```
from selenium import webdriver
#
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#
url = driver.get('http://www.google.com')
#
handles = driver.current_window_handle
print(handles)
```

output:

```
{fc6891c1-e4a9-434b-9f76-fc09bc252e71}
```

Anybody knows how how to get text of that window handle??

Many thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: do you mean source code or text presented on screen(html output)?

Comment: Hi, I would like to get what is on the screen, which is html output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! Easy solution giving correct results.